# how to combine dataframe select queries in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

```
low_enrollment = df[ df['total_enrollment'] < 1000 ]
low_enrollment = df[df['sat_score'] < 1000]
```

How can i combine them in one line? This does not work.

```
low_enrollment = df[ df['total_enrollment'] < 1000 and df['sat_score'] < 1000]
```

Answer (score 3):

You should be using the `&` operator for logical and, not the Python `and`:

```
low_enrollment = df[(df['total_enrollment'] < 1000) & (df['sat_score'] < 1000)]
```

Comment: @Erfan I want to learn more about Pandas, but it's hard to get started, because there are many other senior users such as yourself and Jezrael.

Comment: @ERJAN Man...it seems that it's very easy to misread a comment, with no facial context of any kind.  I actually do want to "break" into Pandas, but, like every other tag, there are gurus like you who are very active.